# Images are not in ImageAndUser model

Tags: python, html, django

Images are not in ImageAndUser model.I wrote in views.py like

```
@csrf_exempt
def upload_save(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = ImageAndUser()
            data.image = request.FILES['image']
            data.save()
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = UserImageForm()

    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/photo.html', {'form': form})
```

index.html is

```
<form action="{% url 'accounts:upload_save' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h2>SEND PHOTO</h2>
        <div class="input-group">
          <label class="input-group-btn">
            <span class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
              SELECT FILE
            <input type="file" style="display:none" name="files[]" multiple>
            </span>
          </label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ p_id }}" name="p_id" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="SEND" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </form>
```

When I put SEND button, upload_save method is read.And my ideal system is image& user's data put in ImageAndUser model.However,now ImageAndUser model does not have the data.I really cannot understand why.But terminal says `<ul class="errorlist"><li>user<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required</li></ul></li></ul>` so I think i cannot get user data.However,I think user can access upload_save method after he log in the site, so I think the system has user data.I do not know why image&user data is not connected.
models.py is

```
class ImageAndUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", verbose_name="imageforegin")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True,)
```

How can I fix this?What should I write it?

My　UserImageForm　is

```
class UserImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ImageAndUser
        fields = (
          'image',
          'user',
        )
```

Comment: Add UserImageForm form code in your question

Comment: @NeErAjKuMaR I added UserImageForm.If u know something, please help me

Comment: Why are you using user field in form? you have to save user from request if user is authenticated

Answer (score 0):

```
@csrf_exempt
def upload_save(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = UserImageForm()

    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/photo.html', {'form': form})
```